# .htaccess rule not catching

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to catch http://mysite.loc/orders/invoice/?id=asdf and redirect it, but it's not catching.  Does anyone have any ideas on something I might've missed?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^orders/invoice?id=([^/]+)$ /store/order/view?hash=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: You certain the .htaccess is in the correct place, your root?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules act on request URIs. The query string (the question mark and everything after it) is not part of the URI so you can't write a pattern to match it.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*)
RewriteRule ^orders/invoice /store/order/view?hash=%1 [R=301,L]
```